# How to RowFilter a column with a period in the name?

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, cube

I have a DataTable pupulated from a cube with the column names declared as:

> [Measures].[Stock Qty]

The DataTable fills correctly, however when trying to apply a RowFilter using:

> "[Measures].[Stock Qty] >= 2000"

I get the following error:

> "[Measures.StockQty] not found

I also tried using just the column name:

> "[Stock Qty] >= 2000"

but this also fails with a not found error.

Is it at all possible to filter a DataTable using column names that contain periods, if so how?

Comment: If you only have the one table within your query, you can just use your column name.

Comment: @NeilKnight Tried that. No go.

Comment: What's the real name of the column in the DataTable? Use the debugger to inspect it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Interestingly according to the column debug: [Measures].[UnitsSold]

Comment: @NeilKnight Removing the Brackets didn't help in either scenarios :(

Comment: What if you use this construct: `"[[Measures].[UnitsSold]]"`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Worth a try but no go. I think I need to revise this whole idea from the top down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename the datatable columns (for replacing period with "_") & they try rowfilter.

Eg.:

```
dataTable.Columns["Stock Qty"].ColumnName = 
                 dataTable.Columns["Stock Qty"].ColumnName.Replace(" ", "_");
```

Comment: It requires additional maintenance that should be avoided. It's a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use the `RowFilter` at all? If you're using .NET 3.5 or higher i would recommend to use Linq-To-DataTable instead which is more powerful and readable:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> filteredRows = tblMeasures.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<int>("Stock Qty") >= 2000);
```

if you need a `DataTable` again:

```
DataTable tblFiltered = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

By the way, if the name of column in the `DataTable` is `"Stock Qty"` your last approach should work since you need to wrap it in brackets.

```
tblMeasures.DefaultView.RowFilter = "[Stock Qty] >= 2000";
```

So you should use the debugger to see the real name and type of the column.

Comment: I agree this is a better solution, however we aren't allowed to use LINQ (Please don't ask why). I am trying to find a quick and dirty solution but this is worthwhile for future use.